# How to get data from server in phonegap android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I need to get data from server having IP:192.188.1.171. and port number 8101 .I need to do socket programming.I am working on cordova 2.7.I study about socket.OI may me the solution.But i don't know where to set my IP .because server is running in PC.I need to parse get that data using socket programming..There is one  **APPKEY** what is the use of that ?

I also saw this 
https://anismiles.wordpress.com/2011/02/03/websocket-support-in-android%E2%80%99s-phonegap-apps/
But it not work on cordova 2.7
can you make some change so that it will work for 2.7
Can you please give me necessary steps to do this  ?

I also find this can you please me in start this
https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy

Answer (score 0):

Could u please check connection established through the socket is successful? because u need static IP address and 8101 port should open to all.

Comment: actually I see my server is running on my machine..?can you please tell me from where i download project and start..Give some step i am too begineer in websocket in android